# C# How to place serial input data into a queue and de-que using a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, queue, serial-port, buffer, backgroundworker

I need to take incoming data from a serial port place the 'ReadExisting' string into a queue, and then de-que back into the user interface.

During the de-que process I will be formatting the incoming string to remove unwanted characters, add LineFeeds (there are no EOL characters in the incoming), etc. and post various parts of the string into several controls (listbox, textbox) for viewing.

This is as far as I have been able to get to create a string (RxString) from incoming data:

```
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,
System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)     
 {         
 RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();         
 this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));     
 }
```

I am able to get the incoming data, but when I try to format it and display it some of the data that comes in gets lost or dropped or something and the text gets unreadable. If I don't format the text & send it straight to a listbox the data is all there, but not useable because of all the extra code characters.

I'd like to handle the (DisplayText) using a backgroundworker so the serial data can come in to a queue so as to not be lost while the backgroundworker handles placing the info on screen. Unless theres a better way.

Comment: There is no need to prefix your title with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Comment: Very unclear, you didn't post the code that does the actual formatting and thus contains the bug.  It is generally pretty important to first assemble the entire response before invoking, ReadExisting() typically only returns one or two characters when you are not debugging.  Leverage ReadLine() if you can.

Comment: What is at the end of the serial port?  What protocol does it use?

Comment: JohnSaunders- thanks It was already one of my tags so didnt know I had to be reundant but added it. makes sense.

Comment: Hans, its not a bug.  it has to do with data coming in faster than the app can format & get back to catch the new incoming data.  in any case I think I have solved it.  i will be using a QUEUE to catch all incoming data regardless of other events, and then dequeue and format each, FIFO as needed.  ReadLine would not work as there is no EOL character being sent- the port never reports an end of line rec'd.

Comment: @user1062142   What kind of device are you connecting to?  What is the protocol, how are the messages to / from the device formatted?  I agree that a queue is the way to go, it is what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the data comes one line at the time, so you could always use the `Queue`-class and use the method `Enqueue` to add the incoming data.

And to get an item from the Background-worker, just use `Dequeue`

Here's a link to the MSDN-article about the `Queue`-class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Example:

```
private Queue<string> data = new Queue<string>();

private void Rx_GetData(e)
{
    var rxString = e.ReadExisting();
    data.Enqueue(rxString);   
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork()
{
    while(rxConn.IsConnected) // Haven't worked with serial connections, so I don't know the proper property here..
    {
        if(data.Count > 0)
        {
            var str = data.Dequeue();
            FormatString(str);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: NoLifeKing- good call. I actually came an obscure across a reference to this approach in searching the past few weeks but did a little testing and it appears that this will work.  thx.

Comment: @NoLifeKing Does C# effectively deal with the infinite loop inside the routine BackgroundWorker_Dowork? I have no C# experience, but I would avoid an infinite loop constantly using CPU resources.

Comment: @Jeff I just added the infinite loop as a placeholder, for performance you should replace `true` with either a check if the connection is still open, and a Thread.Sleep(10) to not hog every resource the system has.

Comment: @NoLifeKing Thank you for continuing my education! I was thinking I use while(data.Count > 0) and let the function exit. Then start the function again when more data is queued. Any issues doing it that way?

Comment: @Jeff, I'm not sure how the background-worker works, but that approach could also be a good one. I'll experiment locally on how the background-worker works and then edit the code.

Comment: @Jeff, Ok, I have concluded that if you use `while(data.Count > 0) { }` , the background-worker will stop working until you manually start it again. To start the background-worker, you will have to run `RunWorkerAsync()` But that can be arranged by having a `Timer` that checks how much data there is in the `Queue` and then start the worker.

Comment: @NoLifeKing Could you place `RunWorkerAsync()` in the function that adds data to the queue? Then there would not be a `Timer` function running and needlessly using CPU resources.

Comment: @Jeff, Of course you can (I actually tried that aswell). But then you should also check on beforehand that it isn't already running. You could always use a public bool to solve that.